# decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(im) -> leads to -> Type Error: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python

Good evening!

I am currently trying to detect the position of various QR Codes in multiple images. I started trying out the following code, but somehow the TypeError Message "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" appears. I tried to convert the image to grayscale but it didn't help. Any ideas? :)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import numpy as np
import cv2

def decode(im) :
  # Find barcodes and QR codes
  **decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(im)**
[enter image description here][1]
  # Print results
  for obj in decodedObjects:
    print('Type : ', obj.type)
    print('Data : ', str(obj.data),'\n')

  return decodedObjects


# Display barcode and QR code location
def display(im, decodedObjects):

  # Loop over all decoded objects
  for decodedObject in decodedObjects:
    points = decodedObject.polygon

    # If the points do not form a quad, find convex hull
    if len(points) > 4 :
      hull = cv2.convexHull(np.array([point for point in points], dtype=np.float32))
      hull = list(map(tuple, np.squeeze(hull)))
    else :
      hull = points;

    # Number of points in the convex hull
    n = len(hull)

    # Draw the convext hull
    for j in range(0,n):
      cv2.line(im, hull[j], hull[ (j+1) % n], (255,0,0), 3)

  # Display results
  cv2.imshow("Results", im);
  cv2.waitKey(0);


# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Read image
  im = cv2.imread('Bild29_grau')

  decodedObjects = decode(im)
  display(im, decodedObjects)
```

Comment: `'Bild29_grau'` seems an unlikely name for an image file (does it really not have an extension?).  Print out `im`, you'll probably find that the image read failed.

Comment: omg, thank you :D now i feel embaressed, i really forgot to add the data type to the image name....